# Pairwise swap of linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to do pairwise swap of linkedlist elements. In place of swapping the elements by data, I am swapping them by swapping the links.

C# code:

```
public LinkedList pairWiseSwapLinks(LinkedList ll)
{
    LinkedList curr = ll;
    LinkedList next = curr.nextNode;

    ll = curr;

    while (curr.nextNode != null && next.nextNode != null)
    {
        curr.nextNode = next.nextNode;
        next.nextNode = curr;

        Console.WriteLine(curr.data);
        Console.WriteLine(next.data);

        curr = curr.nextNode;
        next = curr.nextNode;

        Console.WriteLine(curr.data);
        Console.WriteLine(next.data);
    }

    return ll;
}
```

The input is: 1 -> 3 -> 10 -> 14 -> 16 -> 20 -> 40
Output: 1 -> 10 -> 16 -> 40

Can someone help me out with what mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1. after all swaps, your first node should be 3 instead of 1 in your case, so you should return the originally second node (what if there's only 1?).
2. The reason why 14 is skipped in your case is because you only involve 2 nodes as a pair in each swap. So what happens after the first swap is that the list becomes 3 -> 1 -> 10 -> 16 ... and 14 -> 10 -> 16 so essentially you've lost 14 (i.e. you didn't change the "nextNode" ref in node 1, which should be pointed to 14 in that case).

I don't want to give you the direct solution here but I can give you some hints:

1. You need to involve 3 nodes in each swap.
2. However, what if there are only 1/2 nodes?
3. Adding all the corner cases into your code would make it kinda unreadable, so what if I add a dummy node to the head of the list so eventually I can just write "return dummy.next" instead of bothering finding the current first node?